# Showing New Update Button as user scrolls up

Tags: javascript, react-native, user-interface, react-component

Hello I'm very new to react native and I'm working on a small project. I've to build a news feed tab I've to add a functionality that whenever users scroll up (or drag down the screen),a bubble falls down from top of the screen.

[image: Demo View]

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

**My Approach**
I was searching for a solution and then I found something similar. I made a scrollHandler as follows :

```
import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { NativeSyntheticEvent, NativeScrollEvent, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';

const useHandleScroll = () => {
    const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(true);

    const scrollOffset = useRef(0);

    const handleScroll = useCallback(
        (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {

            // Check if the user is scrolling up or down by confronting the new scroll position with your own one
            const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
            const direction = currentOffset > 0 && currentOffset > scrollOffset.current ? 'down' : 'up';
            // If the user is scrolling down (and the action-button is still visible) hide it
            const isActionButtonVisible = direction === 'up';
            if (isActionButtonVisible !== showButton) {
                setShowButton(isActionButtonVisible);
            }
            // Update your scroll position
            scrollOffset.current = currentOffset;
        },
        [showButton]
    );

    return { handleScroll, showButton };
};

export default useHandleScroll;
```

and I'm using it in my main file as :

```
const { handleScroll, showButton } = useHandleScroll();

{showButton &&  <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.updateView}>
           <Button title="Load More" />
      </TouchableOpacity>}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you tried?

Comment: @RahulBhobe I've edited my post.

Comment: Nice! I upvoted.